# python add custom metadata row/region for images

Tags: image, python-2.7, metadata

Hello I am trying to make software to edit the metadata of an image to include custom properties/groups ([see red boxes in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gc2.png)) in Python 2.7. I have tried PIL to no avail. Could someone please tell me if it is possible and if it is how to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Use the open function, and then parse through the data to find the metadata. Then you can edit that.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Would it be possible for you to give me example code? I am parsing through the data trying to make sense of it and I cannot seem to decode it and show me the metdata to change.

Comment: Look at this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/piexif. I think this library might be useful for you so you won't have to find it manually

Comment: I have read through the documentation; however, the library does not allow the creation of custom property/group